# Print array data 1 by 1 sleeping between each iteration?

Tags: python, arrays, time, loading, sleep

I am trying to make a small Python function that I want to simulate a loading piece. I have an array containing `['|', '\','--','/']` to use the slashes as the loading characters. I strive to re-create the msfconsole's loading page from Metasploit as shown in this image:

[image: screenshot]

Here is the current code that I have:

```
def loadingSlash(time):
    import time
    chars = [
        '|',
        time.sleep(time),
        '/',
        time.sleep(time),
        '--',
        time.sleep(time),
        '\\'
    ]

    chars_clean = ''.join(chars)

pass

loadingSlash(.5)
```

Sorry if the code is way off, I don't usually have to deal with arrays :P

Comment: It's not clear what your question is.